# If $M = \int_{o}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos x}{x+2}dx$ and $N = \int_{0}^{4}\frac{\sin x\cos x}{(x+1)^2}dx$ then the value of $M - N$ is

Tags: integration

I don't think we can directly solve both the definite integrals and get the answer because I checked these two with WolframAlpha and integration is too difficult.

What I tried is if I execute integration by parts on $M$ then:

$$\int\frac{\cos x}{x+2}dx = \frac{\sin x}{x+2} +  \int \frac{\sin x}{(x+2)^2}dx + c$$

and $$N = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{4}\frac{\sin 2x}{(x+1)^2}dx$$

Now we can see that the 2nd element of 1st equation(right side) is somewhat analogous to $N$. But I don't know how to get past this point because the limits and other things are different.

Comment: Without simplifying the integral, just subtract.

Comment: But the limits are different for $M$ and $N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is Like this way...

$$\displaystyle M=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos x}{x+2}dx$$ and $$\displaystyle N=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\sin x\cdot \cos x}{(x+1)^2}dx\;,$$ Then find $M-N$

$\bf{Then\; Solution::}$ Given $$\displaystyle M=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos x}{x+2}dx$$ and $$\displaystyle N=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\sin x\cdot \cos x}{(x+1)^2}dx$$

Now We can write $$\displaystyle N= \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\sin 2x}{(x+1)^2}dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\sin 2x \cdot \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}dx$$

Now Uding Integration by parts, We get

$$\displaystyle N= -\frac{1}{2}\left[\sin 2x \cdot \frac{1}{(x+1)}\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos 2x\cdot \frac{1}{(x+1)}dx$$

Now Let $2x=t\;,$ Then $\displaystyle dx = \frac{1}{2}dt$ and Changing limits, We get

$$\displaystyle N=-\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{4}{\pi+4}+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2\cos t}{t+2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}dt=-\frac{2}{\pi+4}+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos x}{x+2}dx$$

Using $$\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt = \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$$

So We get $$\displaystyle M=-\frac{2}{\pi+4}+N\Rightarrow M-N = -\frac{2}{\pi+4}.$$

Comment: Thank You very much. I think the question that came to me had a misprint and your version is actually correct because your answer is one of the options. Also, I think you have taken the minus sign in the final answer incorrectly.  Then the correct solution is:

$$M - N = \frac{2}{\pi + 4}$$